# django modal not showing up

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

i have retried and followed https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

JS

```
$(function ()
{
    // Create book button
    $(".create-node").modalForm({ formURL: "{% url 'create_node' %}" });
});
```

my URL

```
path('create/', mainapp.NodeCreateView.as_view(), name='create_node'),
```

my view

```
class NodeCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'includes/partial_node_create.html'
    form_class = NodeForm
    success_message = 'Success: Book was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

my button for calling JS

```
<button class="create-node btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">Create book</button>
```

there is still no modal showing up, what else can go wrong?

Comment: One thing you could try is adding `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });` so that the js is initialized

Comment: i have edited my question, i have tried following CRUD from https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

i have tried my JS with alert on ready and it worked. so my JS file is imported correctly.

Comment: Do any errors at all show up when you click the button in the [javascript console of your browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337) My first guess would be that some sort of javascript problem blocks the modal from loading.

Comment: hi matyas, appreciate for your help. i have reformatted my DIR. used to unable to search for jquery JS. but now there is no more error on the console